# Ruby on Rails 5 - Duplicate "Delete" links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

This is the picture of my problem ---> [Duplicate Delete Links Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng11T.png)

I have a comment with two delete links.

This is the order of how I'm rendering the comment form and the comments from partials:

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
<%= render @recipe.comments %>
```

This is the code for **_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@recipe, @recipe.comments.build]) do |f| %>
     <p><%= f.label 'Comment' %> <br> <%= f.text_area :comment %></p>
     <p><%= f.submit 'Post' %></p>
<% end %>
```

This is the code for **_comment.html.erb**

```
<div class="show-text-formatting">
     <p><strong><%= comment.name %></strong></p>
     <p><%= comment.comment %></p>

     <%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.recipe, comment], method: :delete, 
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure want to delete this comment?' } %>
</div>
```

The first delete link have the extension: **/recipes/10/comments/1 (1 is the comment id #)**

Also, when I hover over the second delete link has the extension: **/recipes/10/comment**

The difference between is that the second delete link's extension **doesn't** have a **comment id**

I know that by switching the order of

```
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <%= render 'comments/form' %>
    <%= render @recipe.comments %>
```

to

```
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <%= render @recipe.comments %>
    <%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

would solve my problem, but I want the form to come before the comments.

## EDIT:

The second delete link isn't actually a "second" delete link. It's a delete link for a null object. I still don't know how to get rid of it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Set an order to your comments. Like this:

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
<%= render @recipe.comments.order(created_at: :DESC) %>
```

That should fix your problem. I've had the same issue and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! That saved me a more headache. I was going to figure out how to do the order too, but your answer killed 2 birds with one stone. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. I think it's a Rails bug, but the fix is so easy.

Comment: Is what exactly a Rails bug you think? I have not encountered a similar issue.

Comment: It's the only bug I've found in Rails and since the fix is to specify an order, which you will want to do anyway, then it's not really a high priority to fix. And it only comes up when you have a nested model with an each iterator after a form in the show page of the parent model, like iterating comments in the recipe show page. Why it happens I don't know. I'd have to really dig into the Rails code and that's beyond my skill level to debug.

Answer (score -1):

If you know for sure it's nil object, why don't you add a trigger. I mean we can check the object whether it's nil or not before rendering.